# jQuery marginTop(Left) not working

Tags: jquery

I need to set a block `#note` in the centre of a parent, when you click on the block. The code sets the margin's, but the block does not get to the centre.

```
$('#note').click( function(){
    $('#note').animate({
        position: 'absolute',
        height: '565px',
        width: '700px',
        left: '50%',
        top: '50%',
        marginTop: '-282.5px',
        marginLeft: '-350px',
    }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: What's happening instead?

Answer (score 4):

You have a syntax error:

```
$('#note').click( function(){
    $('#note').animate({
        position: 'absolute',
        height: '565px',
        width: '700px',
        left: '50%',
        top: '50%',
        marginTop: '-282.5px',
        marginLeft: '-350px', // Remove the last ,
        //------------------^ Remove this
    }, 1500);
});
```

The correct syntax:

```
$('#note').click( function(){
    $('#note').animate({
        position: 'absolute',
        height: '565px',
        width: '700px',
        left: '50%',
        top: '50%',
        marginTop: '-282.5px',
        marginLeft: '-350px'
    }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: That will not cause error. http://jsfiddle.net/fmj7yeqr/ So that is not causing the problem here.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy yes it will.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy It caused an error in Chrome!

Comment: Syntax error does not affect the result in Firefox.